# create java function to repeat adding object

Tags: java, json, recursion, serialization, jackson

The desired output is to be like below. Have the node class being serialized at the end so will turn the class into json string for me however the problem is the process need to be looped rather than hard coded.

```
 {"name":"Main","nodes":[{"name":"Tree","nodes":[{"name":"Branch","nodes":[{"name":"Stick","nodes":[{"name":"Leaf"}]}]}]}]}
```

I am trying to loop through this process so that I don't manually keep adding all the objects into each other.

```
    Node mainNode = new Node();
    mainNode.setName("Main");
    String directory = "Tree/Branch/Stick/Leaf";
    Node n1 = new Node();
    n1.setName("Tree");
    Node n2 = new Node();
    n2.setName("Branch");
    Node n3 = new Node();
    n3.setName("Stick");
    Node n4 = new Node();
    n4.setName("Leaf");

    n3.addNode(n4);
    n2.addNode(n3);
    n1.addNode(n2);
    mainNode.addNode(n1);

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    logger.info(gson.toJson(mainNode));
```

Node class

```
public class Node {
  public String name;
  public Node[] nodes;

  public Node(){}
  public Node(String name){
      this.name = name;
  }
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public Node[] getNodes() {
    return nodes;
}
public void setNodes(Node[] nodes) {
    this.nodes = nodes;
}
public void addNode(Node node){
    this.nodes = (Node[]) ArrayUtils.add(this.nodes, node);
}
```

Comment: Why do you need array inside if you store just plain object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better add contructor with child node:

```
Node(String name, Node child) {
    this.name = name;
    if (child != null) {
        addChild(child);
    }
}
```

And define static recursive method:

```
public static Node getNodeTree(String[] leaves) {
        if (leaves.length == 1) {
            return new Node(leaves[0]);
        }

        return new Node(leaves[0], getNodeTree(Arrays.copyOfRange(leaves, 1, leaves.length)));
    }
```

And you will get what you want. And don't forget add check if leaves is null or empty array.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a method that uses recursion...

```
public void addNodeToEnd(Node newNode)
{
    if(this.getNodes().length == 0)
    {
        this.addNode(newNode);
    }
    else
    {
        this.getNodes()[this.getNodes().length - 1].addNodeToEnd(newNode);
    }
}

//make sure you initialize your array of nodes
public Node(String name)
{
  this.name = name;
  this.nodes = new Node[1]; //or however many you want to store
}
```

here is a loop you can use after creating your main node

```
String[] names = directory.split("/");

for(int i = 0; i < names.length; i++)
{
    Node temp = new Node(names[i]);
    mainNode.addNode(temp);
}
```

Comment: When do i call this?

Comment: you would call this everytime you create a new node, once created just call this method on your main node object with the ndoe you just created as it's parameter

Comment: I got a null pointer when trying to use this function instead. Can you post a looping example please?

Comment: so i see why, and it's because in your constructor of the node you never initialize the array containing your nodes. make sure that gets initialized in the body of your constructor